# Connected Pixels Using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I am writing a program which reads in an images and counts how many connected pixels there are. The image contains 4 shapes in black pixels that are on a white background.

In the end, I should have `count = 4;`

I'm having trouble writing a recursion method that reads through each pixel and checks if it is black or white. If it is black, I need to check if there are any other black pixels surrounding it, if not, increase the count by one.

Any ideas?

Trying recursive method:

```
public int recursive(int[][] g, int i,int j){
        //pseudo code
        if(it is white)
            return 0;
        int north = recursive(g,i,j+1);
        int south = recursive(g,i,j-1);
        int west = recursive(g,i-1,j);
        int east = recursive(g,i+1,j);
        int nw = recursive(g,i-1,j+1);
        int ne = recursive(g,i+1,j+1);
        int sw = recursive(g,i-1,j-1);
        int se = recursive(g,i+1,j-1);
        return north+south+west+east+nw+ne+sw+se+1;
    }
```

Another method that gets count:

```
int[][] grid = new int[width][height];

        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                recursive(grid,i,j);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that recursion is the best approach here. Iteration in a nested for loop makes more sense to me.

Comment: @christopher: Why do you say that? I think you're wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following recursive solution:

```
public class Picture {

  private static final int[][] PICTURE = new int[][] { 
    { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, 
    { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }
  };

  private boolean[][] visited;
  private int[][] picture;

  public Picture(int[][] picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
  }

  public int countBlobs() {
    if (picture.length == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    int blobCount = 0;
    visited = new boolean[picture.length][picture[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < picture[i].length; j++) {
        if (!visited[i][j]) {
          if (!isWhite(i, j)) {
            countHelper(i, j);
            blobCount++;
          }
          visited[i][j] = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return blobCount;
  }

  private void countHelper(int i, int j) {
    visited[i][j] = true;
    if (!isWhite(i, j)) {
      for (int deltaI = -1; deltaI <= 1; deltaI++) {
        for (int deltaJ = -1; deltaJ <= 1; deltaJ++) {
          int adjI = i + deltaI;
          int adjJ = j + deltaJ;
          if (inBounds(adjI, adjJ) && !visited[adjI][adjJ]) {
            countHelper(adjI, adjJ);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean inBounds(int i, int j) {
    return i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < picture.length && j < picture[i].length;
  }

  private boolean isWhite(int i, int j) {
    return inBounds(i, j) && picture[i][j] == 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Picture(PICTURE).countBlobs());
  }
}
```

Comment: This really helped! I think one of my main problems was not keeping track of which pixels I had already visited.

Comment: Yes it is a very common paradigm in graph traversal problems.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you want to do is count the number of separate shapes that are in the image, not the number of connected pixels. The number of connected pixels would likely be a number much higher than four.

The way I see it, the best way to do this is to create a separate array that is used to keep track of weather or not a pixel has been included in a shape so that you can ensure that no pixel is included in a shape twice. To count the number of shapes all you have to do is iterate over every pixel in the images using a recursive method to find continuous shapes, and marking every pixel that you include in a shape.

```
//Pass an array if integers as arguments
//Counts the number of distinct continuous "shapes"(blocks of non-zero integers).
public static int countShapes(int[][] image){
    //this boolean array keeps track of what pixels have been included in a shape
    boolean[][] pixelsInShape = new boolean[image.length][image[0].length];
    int shapeCount=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image[0].length; j++){
            if(image[i][j]!=0 && !pixelsInShape[i][j]){
                shapeCount++;
                findShape(image,pixelsInShape,i,j);
            }
        }
    }
    return shapeCount;
}

public static void findShape(int[][] image, boolean[][] pixelsInShape, int row, int col){
    //before being  included in a shape, a pixel must be withing the bounds of the image, not zero, and not already in a shape
    if(row >= 0 && row < image.length && col >= 0 && col < image[0].length && image[row][col]!=0 && !pixelsInShape[row][col]){
        //marks the pixel included in the inclusion array
        pixelsInShape[row][col]=true;
        //recursive calls to all neighboring pixels.
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row,col+1);
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row,col-1);
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row-1,col);
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row+1,col);
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row-1,col+1);
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row+1,col+1);
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row-1,col-1);
        findShape(image,pixelsInShape,row+1,col-1);
    }
}
```